# PostgreSQL multiple authentication methods

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.1

How can I set up multiple authentication methods for the same host/database/user rule?  I want to be able to log in to my postgres user using both `sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres` (without having to enter a PostgreSQL password) and `psql -U postgres --password`.  Something like the following in pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                        md5
local   all             postgres                        peer
```

I can only get one method or the other working at the same time.

Thanks.

(I am using PostgreSQL 9.1).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nope. Only one auth method is supported for any given configuration.

I'd love it if Pg could support fall-back authentication, where if an ident check fails it allows md5 auth instead. It doesn't support this at the moment, though, and I suspect (I haven't verified) that a protocol change would be required to support it.

What you *can* do is store the password in a `$HOME/.pgpass` file for the `postgres` system user. Give it mode 0600 so it's only readable by the `postgres` user and by `root`, both of whom can get direct access to the database files and configuration anyway. That way you get easy admin *and* md5 auth. On some systems you may have to set and create a home directory for the `postgres` user before you can do this. See `getent passwd postgres` to see if if the `postgres` user has a homedir and if so, where it is.

(**UPDATE:** used to read `$HOME/.psqlrc` - which is useful, but `.pgpass` is suitable for password storage)